# Can Samba be configured to have a different password?

Tags: samba

I need Samba to use a different set of credentials for home shares.

The shell login password is different from the Samba login password.

I have disabled the `unix password sync` option, but the Samba password eventually gets replaced by the shell login password.

Is there anything I missed, or is what I'm trying to do not possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Samba password is replaced because you have `pam_smbpasswd` enabled in your PAM configuration. When used in the *auth* group, this module automatically updates the Samba account upon logging in. If you disable it, your passwords will remain separate.

The `unix password sync` option is for the *opposite* direction – it causes the Unix password to be updated when Samba is told to change its own account database.

Comment: I don't see pam_smbpasswd (or pam_smbpass) anywhere in the configuration file.  Google also turned up nothing actionable.

Comment: By "the file", do you mean "all files in `/etc/pam.d`" or something else?

Comment: Both /etc/pam.d/samba and /etc/samba/smb.conf.  In case it helps, I'm running Ubuntu Server 10.04 LTS with Samba 3.4.7.  In the pam.d one, I see 3 @include statements.

Comment: `/etc/pam.d/samba` is only used when logging in over Samba, and I'm talking about normal system logins, so *check the entire pam.d directory*. (The `smb.conf` file is irrelevant.)

Comment: Okay, I found it in two of the pam files and I commented them out.  The password change usually occurs when I'm back to work the following day.  Would a server restart also trigger that pam module to execute (assuming pam_smbpasswd was not commented out)?

Comment: PAM handles user logins and only that. It's not used when restarting the entire system. PAM *is*, however, used when you log in to the system or when you unlock the screensaver.

Answer (score 3):

Just for the record, I have been struggling with this problem and after trying different solutions, I have found the one that seems to work.

I had to uninstall the libpam-smbpass. So a sudo apt-get remove libpam-smbpass fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Just for information:

you should search "pam_smbpass" instead "pam_smbpasswd"

```
# grep smbpass /etc/pam.d/*
/etc/pam.d/common-auth:auth     optional                        pam_smbpass.so migrate
/etc/pam.d/common-password:password     optional                        pam_smbpass.so nullok use_authtok use_first_pass
```

then just delete pam_smbpass from these files.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following to set your Samba Password:

```
sudo smbpasswd -a <username>
```

Then to prevent the Samba Password from sync with the Unix Password on next login do the following:

```
sudo pam-auth-update
```

Then from the interface that pops up Un-check "SMB password synchronization" and hit "OK"